# How can I Configure linter-flake8 on Atom?

Tags: python, atom-editor, flake8

I'm trying to configure `linter-flake8` for python on Atom editor. I used `pip install flake8` and it installed flake8 on `~/.local/bin/`.
I put it on my PATH and add this line on my `coffee.init` file:

```
process.env.PATH = ['~/.local/bin', process.env.PATH].join(':')
```

But still every time I use Atom I get this error:

```
Error: spawn flake8 ENOENT
```

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have any errors when you type flake8 in your terminal?

Answer (score 4):

I solved the same Error in Ubuntu using below command.

```
sudo pip install flake8
```

See below link to have more information.
https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/4642

If your getting *pep8 error* for that you have to install pep8 also.
Below is the command

```
sudo apt-get install pep8
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem because i failed to install flake8 with pip install flake8, I input **sudo apt-get install flake8** to complete installation and problem solved!

first you should input **which flake8** to check if you have successfully installed it

Answer (score 0):

I also had to use `sudo`'s `H` flag for `which flake8` to work.

```
sudo -H pip install flake8
```